# different Virtual directories for same Web application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-config, iis7

When I go to IIS and check SharePoint web applications. another virutal directory has been created for the Web application. for example if the web application is mydomain1 80 there is two virtual directories mydomain180 and mydomain1804e33972a-5b06-4bf4-bc20-ccaa997e75f8.
what is differences between them ?

I thought the real one is mydomain180 but i was wrong because the web.config file was not been updated with safe controlls.

another question is, if there are two or more frontend servers (but one backend)and want to run a powershell script to update web.config file (i.e. to update or add WebConfigModifications) do I need to run the powershell script on all frontends or it updates the database and the new virtuall directory which is created on the fly and all web.config files will contian the changes.
thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand how you end up with multiple Virtual folders, probably you have to share more insight on how you created the Web Applications.

On the other hand, if you have multiple machines in the farm, and you perform manual changes you need to manually update all of the web.config for that particular Web-App. The only way changes are pushed are when you deploy solution packages (.wsp), or in your case if you create Web Parts or Controls.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I usualy using powershell to create Web appklications something lik this: 


New-SPWebApplication -ApplicationPool $appPool -ApplicationPoolAccount $appPoolAccount -Name $name -DatabaseName $dataBaseName -Url $url -Port $port -HostHeader $hostHeader -AuthenticationMethod "Kerberos"